# Has anyone gotten VB highlighting to work in Emacs23?

Tags: emacs, vb6

I have found and installed the [visual basic mode for emacs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/visual-basic-mode.el). It seems to be loading on emacs startup and the VB mode loads when I open a *.bas file. The code is not highlighted at all, however.

I'm using Emacs23, tried it with 21 and saw no difference.

Background for the curious: I am rewriting a set of codes from VB to Python. The syntax highlighting will make it much easier for me to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

When the VB mode loads, is the font-lock-mode enabled?

Try: `M-x describe-variable font-lock-mode` and see if it set.  If not, turn it on by `M-x font-lock-mode` and see if that works.  If so, you can force this automatically by adding this to your `.emacs`:

```
(add-hook 'visual-basic-mode-hook 'turn-on-font-lock)
```

or just turn it on for everything:

```
(global-font-lock-mode 1)
```